gnuplot: How do I extract a date from a string to use it with timecolumn?
In some of my files, date/time is encoded in a character string, e.g. "subject_name/20221006085330_test_something". The following function returns the date (in this case "20221006"):
get_date(c) = substr( strcol(c), strstrt( strcol(c), "/" ) + 1, strstrt( strcol(c), "/" ) + 8 )

How can this function be used together with
stats $DAT i selected_block(1) u ( timecolumn( 2, timeFmt ) ) 

Replacing 2 with get_date("string") does not work, and I cannot explain the meaning of this error: unknown type in magnitude().
# Test script:
reset session

$DAT<<EOD
# cross
string    date     
subject001_name/20200203144309_session021_id     20200203
subject002_name/20200522103745_session079_id     20200522
subject003_name/20210521172330_session201_id     20210521
subject004_name/20220527130250_session047_id     20220527
subject005_name/20220701171757_session081_id     20220701
subject006_name/20220706102238_session003_id     20220706
subject007_name/20221006110417_session081_id     20221006
subject008_name/20230309144707_session901_id     20230309
subject009_name/20230907080602_session003_id     20230907
subject010_name/20240919143733_session022_id     20240919 
EOD

get_date(c) = substr( strcol(c), strstrt( strcol(c), "/" ) + 1, strstrt( strcol(c), "/" ) + 8 )

blocks              = "cross"
selected_block(i)   = word( blocks, i )

timeFmt             = "%Y%m%d"

stats $DAT i selected_block(1) u ( timecolumn( 2, timeFmt ) ) 

pause -1 

stats $DAT i selected_block(1) u ( timecolumn( get_date( "string" ), timeFmt ) ) 

Edit: The following adapted script works, but the statistics show 11 instead of 10 records.
# Test script:
reset session

$DAT<<EOD
# cross
string    date     
subject001_name/20200203144309_session021_id     20200203 
subject002_name/20200522103745_session079_id     20200522 
subject003_name/20210521172330_session201_id     20210521 
subject004_name/20220527130250_session047_id     20220527 
subject005_name/20220701171757_session081_id     20220701 
subject006_name/20220706102238_session003_id     20220706 
subject007_name/20221006110417_session081_id     20221006 
subject008_name/20230309144707_session901_id     20230309 
subject009_name/20230907080602_session003_id     20230907 
subject010_name/20240919143733_session022_id     20240919 
EOD

get_date(c) = substr( strcol(c), strstrt( strcol(c), "/" ) + 1, strstrt( strcol(c), "/" ) + 8 )

blocks              = "cross"
selected_block(i)   = word( blocks, i )

timeFmt             = "%Y%m%d"
date_column(col)    = strptime( timeFmt, get_date(col) )

stats $DAT i selected_block(1) u ( date_column("string") ) 


Well, the short answer would be: use strptime() instead.
The function timecolumn(col,fmt) is explictely for the column number and the date/time format. You cannot insert a function to extract the date/time first. Use strptime() instead (check help strptime).
Script:
### extract date/time from a string for stats
reset session

$Data <<EOD
subject001_name/20221006085330_test_something    1   2   3
subject002_name/20231007090000_test_something    4   5   6
subject003_name/20241007101111_test_something    7   8   9
EOD

myFmt             = "%Y%m%d%H%M%S"
get_datetime(col) = substr(_s=strcol(col), _t=strstrt(_s,"/")+1, _t+13)
t(col)            = strptime(myFmt, get_datetime(col))

set table $DateTime
    plot $Data u (get_datetime(1)) w table
unset table
print $DateTime

stats $Data u (t(1)) nooutput
print "Min: ", STATS_min, "  =  ", strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",STATS_min)
print "Max: ", STATS_max, "  =  ", strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",STATS_max)
### end of script

Result:
20221006085330
20231007090000
20241007101111

Min: 1665046410.0  =  2022-10-06 08:53:30
Max: 1728295871.0  =  2024-10-07 10:11:11

Addition 1:
If your substring before the date was constant (which is not in your case) you could have used timecolumn() in the following way.
myFmt = "subject_name/%Y%m%d%H%M%S"
stats $Data u (timecolumn(1,myFmt)) nooutput

Addition 2:
Yet, another method using timecolumn() with variable pre-string. Before stats set the datafile separator to / and consider column 2 as the date/time column. However, this again implies that you have the same number of slashes / before the date.
set datafile separator "/"
myFmt = "%Y%m%d%H%M%S"
stats $Data u (timecolumn(2,myFmt)) nooutput
set datafile separator whitespace

Addition 3:
Here is a version with addressing columns by name, but avoiding that the header "string" is (mis)interpreted as a number (something like 6.91e-317, in fact 0) which would result in the date 1970-01-01 00:00:00. You need to insert a condition: if pseudocolumn 0 (i.e. $0 line number, zero-based) is smaller than 1 then return NaN which will not be taken into account for stats.
Script:
### extract date/time from a string for stats
reset session

$Data <<EOD
# cross
string    date
subject001_name/20200203144309_session021_id     20200203
subject002_name/20200522103745_session079_id     20200522
subject003_name/20210521172330_session201_id     20210521
subject004_name/20220527130250_session047_id     20220527
subject005_name/20220701171757_session081_id     20220701
subject006_name/20220706102238_session003_id     20220706
subject007_name/20221006110417_session081_id     20221006
subject008_name/20230309144707_session901_id     20230309
subject009_name/20230907080602_session003_id     20230907
subject010_name/20240919143733_session022_id     20240919
EOD

myFmt             = "%Y%m%d%H%M%S"
get_datetime(col) = ($0<1 ? NaN : \
    strptime(myFmt, substr(_s=strcol(col), _t=strstrt(_s,"/")+1, _t+13)))

stats $Data u (get_datetime("string")) nooutput
print "Records: ", STATS_records
print "Min: ", STATS_min, "  =  ", strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",STATS_min)
print "Max: ", STATS_max, "  =  ", strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",STATS_max)
### end of script

Result:
Records: 10
Min: 1580740989.0  =  2020-02-03 14:43:09
Max: 1726756653.0  =  2024-09-19 14:37:33


Your addition 2 works perfectly! Fortunately, the old files I have to work with always have the format "subject_name/%Y%m%d%H%M%S_session_id" in the first column. So, if the separator is set to "/", the second column always starts with date/time.

@magfan yes, I noticed the problem with stats interpreting the header string as number (something like 6.91e-317, in fact 0) which would result in the date 1970-01-01 00:00:00. Well, setting and re-setting the separator might lead to confusion with column numbering. But as I understand, you wanted to call the column by name "string" not by number 1 or 2. I will think about it.

Yes, I prefer to call columns by their name, as their position in the file can be different, apart from the first column. And there can be a few hundred columns.
